# Нужно ли делать проверку на Assigned перед вызовом Free или FreeAndNil?

Tags: delphi, объекты

Довольно часто в коде встречается вот такая конструкция:

```
MyObj: TObject;

..

if Assigned(MyObj) then
  FreeAndNil(MyObj);
```

или:

```
if Assigned(MyObj) then
  MyObj.Free;
```

Логика пишущего код скорее всего такая - "проверим указатель на валидность, перед тем как к нему обращаться".

Вопрос, нужна ли проверка `if Assigned` перед вызовом `FreeAndNil` или `Free`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, такая проверка не нужна.

Процедура `Assigned` не проверяет валидность указателя, как многие иногда полагают, она лишь проверяет указатель на `nil` ([справка](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Assigned)).

Метод `Free` уже содержит проверку на `nil` в себе (проверяется по исходникам `TObject.Free`).

Процедура `FreeAndNil` присваивает указателю `nil` и так же вызывает `Free`, в котором присутствует эта проверка (также проверяется по исходникам `SysUtils.FreeAndNil`).